# Where JSON in Laravel gives error SQLSTATE[42000]: check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I have tried to get data from database with laravel Where JSON. But it gives an error. I have added the data like this.

```
$event = new Event;
$event->scores = json_encode([['user_ids' => [1,2,3,4],'score' => 15]]);
$event->save();
```

When I want to return the data in database.

```
Event::where('scores->score',15)->get()
```

Shows this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$."score"'
>   = ?' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `events` where `scores`->'$."score"' = 15)

My MariaDB version is 10.2.1

Comment: Well first off... `syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' `

Comment: Ow i fixed it, the data added but it gives the error

Comment: And if you try `Event::where('scores',15)->get()`

Comment: With `Event::where('scores',15)->get()` brings an empty value

Comment: Because it worked and there are no rows with a score of 15? Or, did your save work and this select is not returning what we expect still?

Comment: But already it is added to database, why it dose not bring an result? it is stored like this in db `[{"user_ids":[1,2,3,4],"score":15}]`

Comment: Wait, now I am more confused...Are you trying to SQL query a string of JSON? Is there a column on the table named `score`?

Comment: I want to return the data that i have saved as JSON in mysql db. It is saved as JSON but the Laravel query builder dose not bring anything.

Comment: That syntax is not yet available in MariaDB.  See https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13594

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Array & JSON Casting**

On your Event model you need to add

```
class Event extends Model {
      protected $casts = ['scores'=>'array'];
// ...
}
```

and then when saving the data

```
$event = new Event;
// you had what appeared to be an extra array, that could cause the issue?
$event->scores = ['user_ids' => [1,2,3,4],'score' => 15]; 
$event->save();
```

Then the data will be saved as JSON automatically as long as the column type is TEXT or JSON(new versions of MySQL).

See Array & JSON casting on the Laravel Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

**Then to retrieve:**

```
Event::where('scores->score', '15')->get();
```

Here is the relevant documentation for JSON Where clauses
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#json-where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

Again, pretty confused as to what you are asking. Might help to see structure of the table or what the expected SQL should look like.

If you are trying to return rows based off values contained inside a string of JSON stored on the table... Then you need to do something like...

```
->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(score, '[15]' )")->get();
```

Or something along those lines... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: It brings an empty value

Comment: Show raw SQL that returns desired results nad we can talk more about how to accomplish that with Laravel.

Comment: It just returns `[]`